# Writing determinant as a finite series of powers of $\sin{x}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Consider the function

> $$f(x)=\begin{vmatrix}
> \sin{2x} & \cos^2{x} & \cos{4x} \\
> \cos^2{x} & \cos{2x} & \sin^2{x}\\
> \cos^4{x} & \sin^2{x} & \sin{2x}
> \end{vmatrix}$$

The question is: "If $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i (\sin{x})^i=a_0+a_1\sin{x}+\cdots+a_n(\sin{x})^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then find $a_0$". I have seen solutions of this question, where they simply plug $x=0$ in the expression, and obtain $f(0)=a_0 = \begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{vmatrix} = -1.$ (See [Site 1](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/ifleft-beginmatrix-sin2x-cos-2-x-cos4x-cos/) and [Site 2](https://www.doubtnut.com/question-answer/if-sin2xcos2xcos4xcos2xcos2xsin2xcos4xsin2xsin2xa0-a1-sinx-a2sin2x-ansinn-x-then-the-value-of-a0-is--20475839)) However, we can only do this if $f(x)$ is indeed equal to $\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i (\sin{x})^i$. But I am unable to get rid of $\cos{x}$ in the expression which comes due to $\sin{2x}$. First substitute $\sin{x}=t$, $$\begin{vmatrix}
\sin{2x} & \cos^2{x} & \cos{4x} \\
\cos^2{x} & \cos{2x} & \sin^2{x}\\
\cos^4{x} & \sin^2{x} & \sin{2x}
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
2t\cos{x} & 1-t^2 & 1-8t^2+8t^4 \\
1-t^2 & 1-2t^2 & t^2 \\
(1-t^2)^2 & t^2 & 2t\cos{x}
\end{vmatrix}$$
Expanding along $R_2$, coefficient of $\cos{x}$ comes out to be $-(4t^5-4t^3+2t)$, which is not necessarily zero. What is happening? Shouldn't the answer be "No such $a_0$ exists"?

Comment: I mean, one might argue that since the question is given in the if-then form,  you are allowed to stipulate the if part,. but it would be more satisfying to show it is possible, yes

Comment: What Alan said. But technically, since there is no such representation, you’d have a contradiction, so you could pick any value $a_0.$

Comment: What should I write as the solution to this question then? "No such $a_0$ exists" or $a_0=-1$ ?

Comment: @Sam - your link to 'site 1' is subtly different to your question. It only has three terms rather than n+1 terms.

Comment: @Blitzer I also didn't understand that, maybe the OP there missed to put cdots in between the terms.